# Detect when Socket Connection is disconnected C / C++ Unix

Tags: c++, c, sockets, disconnect

I know this question has been discussed several times, but I didn‘t manage to detect whether a socket disconnected in C / C++ on Unix.
Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the socket might be closed by the peer.

It very depends on where you want to detect the disconnection.

If you are in the blocking `recv`:
[manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html)

> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred.  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the error.

> When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the
> return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

If you want to know on `send`:
[manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html)

> On success, these calls return the number of bytes sent.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.